# The InAppBrowser's executeScript method?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Can anybody try to explain, why the `executeScript` method is not working with any domain except the `'https://example.com'` domain and when i try to change it with any other domain the InAppBrowser window displays empty screen.

```
openPage(){
    this.browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com','_blank','hidden=yes,location=yes,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
    this.browser.on('loadstart')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      this.browser.executeScript({
        code: `(function() { window.location.href = 'https://example.com'; })()`
      })
      this.browser.show();
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace following code

```
 this.browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com','_blank','hidden=yes,location=yes,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
```

with

```
 this.browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com','_blank','location=no);
```